# Do something depend on element id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have some function inside click action. I need to stop this function if the last of my html list element will be have some id, so I do this but function does not work... Can you help me?

```
carousel_controls_buttons.on('click', function(){
    var settings_list_last_element_id = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'r_00';
    if (settings_menu_element.last(id === settings_list_last_element_id)) {
    }
    else {
        renumNext();
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `return false;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

`if (settings_menu_element.last(id === settings_list_last_element_id))`

to

`if (settings_menu_element.last().attr('id') === settings_list_last_element_id)`

**Edit:**

```
if (settings_menu_element.last().attr('id') === settings_list_last_element_id){
    return false;
} else {
    renumNext();
}
```

Or even better:

```
if (settings_menu_element.last().attr('id') !== settings_list_last_element_id){
    renumNext();
}
```

Comment: ok, its works but for the first element on my list :) that's good nevertheless, much thx

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statement looks a bit odd. Try something like this instead:

```
carousel_controls_buttons.on('click', function(){

    // Do nothing if last element has a certain id-attribute
    if (settings_menu_element.last().attr("id") === 'r_00') {
        return false;
    }

    renumNext();
});
```